# IOS 8 and App Store wrong language

Tags: ipad

Since the new IOS 8 I have had several problems with my iPad. One of which is the App Store is in Turkish I have checked my country and language everything is fine. Since its in Turkish it will not allow me to update any programs saying I need to switch to the U.S. Store, how do I do that? Several of my games no longer work  after the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

All the way at the bottom right corner of the Apple Store screen there is a round symbol representing which country Apple store are you in.

[image: country]

Click on it and it will bring you choices to switch country.

Answer (score 1):

Close the open apps on your device and go to 1) Settings 2) Itunes & App Store 3) select: Apple ID
4) choose: View Apple ID  5) provide your password. It should be working. Success!

Answer (score 0):

Beside what @Buscar웃 suggests, I would recommend:

1. Go to **Settings > iTunes & App Store**
2. Logout your Apple ID
3. Re-login Apple ID: If iOS detects the App Store language does not match your Apple ID's mapped Store location, it will launch App Store & switch to that language.

p.s. I always use this trick to switch between Japan & Hong Kong store.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. Here is what worked for me:

1. Go to iOS settings.
2. Select iTunes & App Store.
3. Tap **View Apple ID**.
4. Enter your password.
5. iOS prompted that "your App Store is not the U.S. store. you will be redirected to the U.S. App Store right now." I tapped **Okay** and the U.S. App Store popped up :)